# Is it safe to configure Lock Escalation as 'AUTO' for partitioned tables

Tags: sql-server, timeout, deadlock, locking

LOCK_ESCALATION= AUTO.

In one of our Data warehousing product we use partitioned tables. They are partitioned based on an integer column. We have implemented partitioning here so we can easily switch data across tables.

Environment Details:

```
SQL Version: SQL Server 2016
Table: FACT
Approx Size: 100-500 GB
No of Partitions: 100
Partition Column: RunID (int)
```

Activity: Parallel ETL Processing
Applications Involved in ETL: SSIS package

We have a SSIS Package which is written to process in parallel for 3 RunIDs (3 Partitions). These 3 runs are few minutes/hours apart from each other.

We have faced a situation where we observe a time-out when below condition occurs.
Below is the observation:
Run 3 (Truncate seems to be blocked for an hour)
Run 2 (Bulk Insert, this is timed-out)
We Suspect either Run2 or Run1 is conflicting with Run3, eventually causing a time-out for Run2.

| Run 3 | Run 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Truncate with partition | Bulk insert |
| partion 3 | Partion 2 |

To avoid this conflict, we are considering to set the Lock Escalation of this partitioned table to AUTO.
So, the locks would remain at HoBT level. While we are processing concurrently for 3 different Partitions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#set--lock_escalation---auto--table--disable--

Before Implementing, we wanted an opinion to understand the risks associated by using this configuration for a particular table which is only Queried/Processed for one partition at a time. Could this change introduce deadlocks? Since the early adopters of this feature have experienced deadlocks:

Paul Randal: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2330-lock-escalation/

Brent Ozar: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/11/partition-level-locks-confusing/

Comment: From the very ancient [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms184286(v=sql.105)) "HoBT-level locks usually increase concurrency, but introduce the **potential** for deadlocks when transactions that are locking different partitions each want to expand their exclusive locks to the other partitions. In **rare instance**s, TABLE locking granularity **might** perform better." I doubt it's a major problem, unless you are seeing actual deadlocks? And you would anyway only see them if working on multiple partitions at once in a single batch.

Comment: "We Suspect either Run2 or Run1 is conflicting with Run3, eventually causing a time-out for Run2."  You shouldn't guess.  The blocking may be between the ETL and readers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES worth it but consider the trade off scenarios and also do `benchmarking` before and after as well as non prod thorough testing.

Setting the `LOCK_ESCALATION option to AUTO` for your partitioned table could help reduce lock contention and improve concurrency for your parallel `ETL` processing. By keeping the locks at the `HoBT (Heap or B-Tree) level`, it allows for finer-grained locking at the `partition` level.

However, as you mentioned, there are some potential risks and considerations associated with this change. While `partition-level` locks can help reduce `contention` and improve `concurrency`, they may also introduce the possibility of `deadlocks`. With f`iner-grained locking`, there is a chance of increased lock conflicts between concurrent processes accessing different partitions.   test and monitor system for potential deadlock scenarios after making this change.

Additionally, finer-grained locking at the partition level can result in increased `memory` overhead due to the maintenance of individual locks for each partition. If you have a large number of partitions  Ensure  *enough memory* to accommodate the change

`benchmark` and compare the performance impact before and after implementing this change. Consider temporarily disabling partition-level locking (`LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)` during maintenance operations like `index rebuilds` or partition switching to optimize these operations.

Test this change in a `non-prod environment .`